# .NETのSslStreamでデータの終端を判断したい

Tags: c#, .net

SslStreamでサーバーサイドの実装をしています。
読み取るデータがない状態でRead()を呼ぶと、ブロッキングされてしまいます。
戻り値に0が返ってくると思っていましたが、返ってきません。
これ以上読むべきデータがない状態を判断することはできますか？

同じSslStreamを使用してクライアントの実装をしたら0が返ってくるので判断できました。
サーバーサイドの実装だけがブロッキングしてしまっているので困っています。

NetWorkStreamではDataAvailableというプロパティがあるのでデータがそれ以上ない状態を判断できますが、SslStreamの場合のやり方がわかりません。

```
    public static byte[] Read(SslStream stream)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        byte[] resBytes = new byte[1024];
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int n = stream.Read(resBytes, 0, resBytes.Length);
                if (0 < n)
                {
                    ms.Write(resBytes, 0, n);
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }

        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: `Read` がブロックされるのは正しい動きなので仕方ないです。 `SslStream.BeginRead`で非同期処理にしてはどうでしょうか。 http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.net.security.sslstream.beginread.aspx

Comment: ありがとうございます。
パフォーマンスの観点から、いずれ非同期に変更するつもりですが、今知りたいのはどちらかというと、現在読むべきデータが残っているかという点なのです。無ければ切断するという処理を書きたいです。

Comment: 了解。では、 ReadTimeout, CanTimeuot のプロパティを使うことで良さそうですね。 IOException が出るはず。

Comment: 現状はTimeoutを設定して切断するのがよさそうです。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「これ以上読むべきデータがない状態」とは何かにより答えが変わりますが、「送信側で送ったすべてのデータを、受信側で読み終わった状態」を指すのであれば、Stream関係のクラスにそのような機能はありません。(コードやコメントを見た感じからそう仮定して以下書いています。違っていたらごめんなさい)

SSLなので下層のプロトコルはTCPですが、TCPはストリーム指向でメッセージ境界の概念がないので、ユーザーがコード上でデータ区切りを指定しないといけません。Microsoftのサンプル
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.net.security.sslstream(v=vs.110).aspx
では、`if (messageData.ToString().IndexOf("<EOF>") != -1)`と、アプリで勝手に終端マークを決めて通信しています。このように終端を決めるか、TCPヘッダやHTMLのContent-Lengthのように序盤に長さを送るか、他にも方法はありますが、基本はそんな感じです。

正常な処理ルートでタイムアウトによる強制中断をすると、ただ回線が混んでいてパケットの到着が遅れているだけの場合でも、問答無用で切断してしまいます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。tcpの仕様上、その意味での終端がソケットで判断できないのは理解しています。質問の意図は、現在ソケットのキューに溜まっているデータがあるかないかの判断でした(遅延などで遅れているとしても今無ければ無いとしたい)。

そもそも何をしたいかと言いますと、keepaliveで一通りリクエストを取り終わった後の待機をしたくない(かつタイムアウト例外はなるべく使いたくなかった)というのが問題の発端です。
もちろん即断してしまうと、まだリクエストが連続で来ている途中の可能性があるのは否めませんが。

Comment: そうでしたか。早とちり失礼しました。  
DataAvailable()相当で良いのであれば、StreamなのでCanRead()はどうでしょうか。

Comment: canreadはtrueになってしまうようです。これはストリームが読み取り操作可能かどうかという意味のフラグかもしれません。
無難にタイムアウトでいこうと思います。

Answer (score 0):

MSDNの[クラス情報](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.net.security.sslstream(v=vs.110).aspx)を見た感じだと、これ以上読むべきデータが無いかを確認する方法はなさそうですね。
以下のような感じでタイムアウト(以下の例は0.1秒)を設定して、ずっと待ち続けないようにするのではダメですか？

```
sslStream.ReadTimeout = 100;
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
やはりTimeoutを設定するしかなさそうです。